# Fancybox's prev and next buttons do not appear

Tags: fancybox

While editing a template i got stuck at the point of working with fancybox. I noticed that the 'next' and 'prev' buttons are not appearing. Are there specific js commands for making them appear? Or where should i look more exactly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to set the same `rel` attribute in all your anchors that belong to the same gallery like:

```
<a class="fancybox" href="{target 01 here}" rel="gallery">one</a>
<a class="fancybox" href="{target 02 here}" rel="gallery">two</a>
...etc
```

Answer (score 1):

Without any code posted I can only guess what could be the problem. Try the following two...

1. Check if you have added the `fancybox-buttons.js` to your page
2. Make sure you have the `next` and `prev` images that comes with fancybox to your correct images directory.

Hopefully this should fix your problem. If it doesn't then update your question by posting your code for more help.