# Fancybox: Next and previous image within different DIVs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

The HTML structure looks like this:

```
<div id="gallery" class="container">

    <div class="thumbs-holder">
        <div class="thumbs-center-area">
            <div class="thumb-back">
                <a class="fancybox" href="images/image1.jpg">
                    <img class="thumb" src="images/thumbnails/image1.jpg" title="Image 1" />
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="thumbs-holder">
        <div class="thumbs-center-area">
            <div class="thumb-back">
                <a class="fancybox" href="images/image2.jpg">
                    <img class="thumb" src="images/thumbnails/image2.jpg" title="Image 2" />
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    ...

</div>
```

With the code above, when I click the thumbnail, it opens lightbox image (fancybox), but can't get the "next" and "prev" buttons in the lightbox to get the image from next div. It shows only the image from one div.

How can I make fancybox "prev" and "next" works with HTML structure like this?

Comment: Where exactly are you wanting to display the buttons?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fancybox's prev and next buttons do not appear](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220618/fancyboxs-prev-and-next-buttons-do-not-appear)

Comment: basically you are missing to set the `rel` attribute in your links to create the gallery.

Comment: Indeed. That was the thing. Thanks