# Fancybox gallery with type=ajax

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have links, which when clicked need to fetch content via Ajax and show it in Fancybox.
The code in the most-stripped down form:

**Markup:**

```
<a href="some_ajax_link/1" class="anchor">Click</a>
<a href="some_ajax_link/2" class="anchor">Click</a>
...
```

**JS**

```
$('a.anchor').fancybox({
  type: 'ajax'
});
```

### Problems

1. This opens only the link clicked, with no navigation arrows.
2. Using the helper buttons, does give the buttons helper, but next doesn't
   load the next link's content, instead loads the same content.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fancybox's prev and next buttons do not appear](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220618/fancyboxs-prev-and-next-buttons-do-not-appear)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing to add `rel="gallery"` or `data-fancybox-group="gallery"` (if using HTML5 `DOCTYPE` **and** fancybox v2.x) attribute to your anchors

```
<a data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="some_ajax_link/1" class="anchor">Click</a>
<a data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="some_ajax_link/2" class="anchor">Click</a>
```

Comment: hey, data-fancybox-group worked. For some reason, I was adding rel, that didn't work.

Thanks.